# How would a magician trick scientists into believing he is using science?

Tags: magic, scientific-development, modern-age

Now let's say there is a magician. We'll say he like a DnD wizard or something, so he does stuff like create food out of thin air and turns people he doesn't like into lizards. He doesn't want to restrict his magic use at all, but he doesn't want all the scientists to freak out or anything. Specifically, he wants his magic to seem to have *scientific* explanations.

- He has various powers of a DnD wizard
- He uses them in public frequently at whim

  - He doesn't try to hide it at all. He literally flies to work (as a party magician) and conjures stuff up all the time.
- He wants scientists to believe his acts fit within current science

  - He doesn't want to change science though. His magic has to fit within our **current** understanding of science. He can't create new scientific theories to explain it.
  - Specifically, it has to have a **specific** scientific explanation. Most scientists believe that everything fits into science, but this magician wants them to know *how* his magic fits in.
- He doesn't want to invade people's minds with magic (illusion is okay)
- He wants to expend the least of effort possible.

  - Like a DnD wizard, any extra spells he need to keep this charade up means he has less spells for more important stuff, like hypnotizing the pigeons to poop on people's cars.
  - He doesn't want to use up too much time keeping the charade up either.

In case you're wondering, this magician is not necessarily myself. You can believe me because I am telling you the truth.

Comment: DnD = Dungeons and Dragons? Related: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/believable-magical-transmutation-of-elements?rq=1, http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/101/in-a-world-of-science-and-magic-how-is-magic-explained-scientifcally?rq=1 Also, can you list specific abilities?

Comment: @HDE226868 From the [mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dungeons_%26_Dragons_rulebooks#Dungeons_.26_Dragons_3rd_edition_and_v3.5) of spells available to wizards in Dungeons and Dragons v. 3.X, this wizard can do anything under the sun (and some things over it). I believe the _fly_ spell is 2nd/3rd level (out of 9) and _hypnotize_ is 1st. The typical _fireball_ is also 3rd level.

Comment: "He has various powers of a DnD wizard" - you mean, nerdery, rote leveling up by grinding (probably murdering countless rats), and knowledge of obscure spell stats?

Comment: @DVK He generally hides those things, as not even science can explain those things.

Comment: What is the difference between magic and science? If someone is trying to understand and study magic (like a D&D wizard, not a D&D sorcerer though) and they use the [scientific method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method) to study it, I'm not sure there *is* a difference between science and magic to *scientists* (to peasants there may). I guess what I'm asking is **in an environment with scientists, what would make something "magical" be "unscientific."**

Comment: @CaptainMan The scientists understand science as we do, and most of the world obeys it. Our physics are only broken in relation to this guy, but he wants us to think our physics is correct.

Comment: Any sufficiently analyzed magic is indistinguishable from science.

Comment: Scientists aren't used to having experiments actively try to lie to them, which -- as the history of perpetual motion and ESP scams has demonstrated -- sometimes makes them _easier_ to fool. Which is why various stage magicians have gotten involved in helping to examine such claims. James Randi was one of the better-known and more respected folks working in that area, but there have been others.

Comment: "Most scientists believe that everything fits into science" - This is not true, there are numerous phenomena that don't connect to what we currently know, e.g. what dark energy is

Comment: If you were willing to advance current scientific understanding forward by say 50 years then you might be able to claim holograms or nanotechnology of some sort

Comment: @TomJNowell: Science is not "what we know". Science is "a search for the truth". Therefore, to a practicing scientist (and indeed any rational person) anything that doesn't fit into science cannot possibly exist. If magic is real it only means that our understanding of physics is incomplete. It doesn't mean that magic is unscientific.

Comment: how about cold fusion? I'm pretty sure there are scientists willing to believe you!

Comment: Have a read of "stranger in a strange land" by Heinlein. The hero pretends to be using stage magic whilst using the real thing.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is more-or-less the premise behind White Wolf's [Mage: The Ascension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mage:_The_Ascension) RPG.  You can do all the magic you want, so long as it's *plausible*.  When you do implausible things, bad things happen to you.

Comment: Is he trying to hide the existence of magic? Or does he live in a world where magic is real and well-known but he simply doesn't want people to know that *he* is one?

Comment: @colmde He is trying to hide the existence of magic. He isn't trying hard, but he at least wants to try a little. He may like trolling people, but even he wouldn't cause society upheavals and such, nor does he want to be a celebrity.

Comment: Magic is science we don't yet understand. All he needs is to say "I'm manipulating space-time using my special talents" and scientists will rush to study his gifts

Comment: Many scientists are notoriously bad at trying to explain how "magic" (illusion, slight of hand, etc) is done; ask James Randi. They will themselves theorize fantastic gadgets (cameras on the end of fingers, miniature electromagnets) rather than the expert manipulation of human perception and cognition.

Comment: "In case you're wondering, this magician is not necessarily myself. You can believe me because I am telling you the truth." In other words, 'Trust me. I'm a magician.'?

Answer (score 36):

**Props**

The easiest and simplest way for your Magician to use his magic is simply to use it with various props he may have. He doesn't need to explain anything, scientists will work VERY hard to explain anything they don't understand. All they need is a carrot to run after.

I.e.: Your magician is flying to work. All he needs is to take out his skateboard (to which he duck-taped a couple of spray painted cans - or any fancier sci-fi looking skateboard) and fly to work while either holding it or standing on it etc... The moment he's seen, it's not magic that'll be on everyone's mind, it's how the guy invented some crazy flying skateboard.

He's conjuring stuff out of mid-air. Any kind of Hollywood beam gun or teleporting microwave like machine will do the trick to have people willingly fool themselves in disbelieving any magic is at work.

Comment: Props are good. So basically he's not a magician, but an inventor!

Comment: Straw scientist, maybe. Anyone remotely competent will be quick to point out that no matter what he has ductaped under the thing it's not going to make it fly, let alone be stable or controllable. If you want to run this a light hearted comedy world where people don't care about such things you can pull this; If you're at all interested in keeping this believable your wizard will have to tone down quite a bit.

Comment: it was a simplistic example. If the wizard can conjure stuff out of thin air he can conjure out an imagined hoverboard 5000. And the point was *props*. And my point is, (take new horizon as an example then) have a darker blotch appear on an infra red picture of something taken millions of miles out in space of an object and you end up with a few dozen scientific theories on what that blotch signifies. Scientists will be sceptical about anything, question anything, and come up with theories for everything, but **magic** will never be one of them. Throw them a bone. they will bite.

Comment: @PyRulez Is there really a difference?

Comment: @Spacemonkey If the skate board doesn't work, a hang glider or something would work.

Comment: Any SF writer will agree with this. A widget and a plausible explanation can be enough to justify suspension of disbelief. Some day I'm going to invent the positive-logic optical transducer just so i can build PLOT devices.

Comment: One thing you must get in mind if it appear to be the greatest scientist in the world is that many many people (and not only good people) is going to try to get its inventions.

Comment: re: (5 comments up) The point @Cubic raised, which I happen to agree with, is that the presence of a prop, whether or not you know it's a prop, doesn't constitute an explanation. It _suggests_ one, yes, but scientists are then going to want to know how the prop works, and how they can build one for themselves. (uh, I mean, for science.) When they can't reproduce the effect, they're going to look for other explanations.

Comment: @Spacemonkey That's for unknown phenomena. The wizard we're talking about is supposedly trying to sell what he does as things that are _already possible_. That just _doesn't work_.

Comment: @keshlam Emphasize on the _willing_ part. The scientific method gives every scientist with domain knowledge not only the right, but the _duty_ to call bs when they see someone make bs claims. In-universe scientists don't have willing suspension of disbelief when it comes to science.

Comment: a@spacemonkey: see my other comments. The first step is realizing that there is something that needs to be questioned, and that it may not be the obvious thing. Scientists are as vulnerable to deliberate misdirection as anyone else; they just have better tools for working through the problem to isolate the cause.

Comment: I'm guessing that last comment was directed at Cubic - @Cubic (and others) - yet we have to come up with an answer that fit OP's requirements, I'm not saying Props do not have flaws, but [...]

Comment: if the wizard has to go around always being able to provide hard scientific proof to the most sceptical of scientists he would have to put up the illusion of going by perfectly standard means (magically flying with a helicopter or maintaining the illusion of being on top a double decker bus, etc...) which defeats the purpose of him using magic on a whim for every day tasks as stated in the question. (He might as well have a helicopter OR take the bus.)

Comment: Also I'd like to point out that nothing states in the original question that he can't have any obsessed scientists pulling out their hair over unproven technological feats.

Comment: So...let users on **StackExchange** come up with reasons as to how he does it.

Comment: He will probably have to be more crafty than flying skateboards, but I would imagine he could use plausible props for most of things.

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether the things he has duck-taped to the skateboard are convincing. Scientists will recognize them to be a disguise, however, they won’t come up with the explanation that it’s a kind of magic. They will simply assume that there is another trick, still being on the grounds of physics. And while they focus on finding out how the skateboard works they miss all they other impossible things he does…

Comment: It takes a lot of work to make scientist believe that an implausible device works.  Take the EM drive as an example, or the various so called cold fusion plants that are out there.

Answer (score 26):

## Let himself be exposed... as a fraud

All he needs to do is [visit Randi](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/One_Million_Dollar_Paranormal_Challenge) and use a magic trick rather than actual magic and then use some mind manipulation to get as many media as possible to write about it. Or maybe if he feels uncomfortable visiting Randi (as in a magic world Randi would probably be a magician supressing the powers of others) he could simply set up a situation where he gets exposed for faking stuff. Like having a trapdoor suddenly open somewhere 'by mistake' whilst on television or something.

After that it would still be a wise idea to not do stuff that is *too* impossible. For example if he flies to work everyday on a skateboard scientists *will* freak out and will do anything possible to figure out how he's doing it. Conjuring stuff out of thin air however is quite doable for a real-world magician (as long as it doesn't literally materialize in thin air), it just takes money and preperation normally. Practically the wisest thing for him to do is study real world magicians and learn what they can and can not do and limit himself to those things. And whenever he gets in a tight spot 'slip up' (using real magic) in the way a real world magician would slip up.

Comment: That is hilarious, Randi actually being an evil magician.

Comment: For flying to peoples houses: Just let yourself be exposed climbing out of an old Minivan behind the house while an illusion is flying to the house. Maybe have some kind of fancy projector on the Minivan... And everybody will be like "yeah, some fancy projection in the sky" - Of course this would break down if people tried to analyse everything about you. But who has the time? There are millions of frauds, once you were exposed no one cares. - You'd only have to do this once - after that people will simply say "he found a way to better hide the van"

Comment: @Falco doing a convincing protection in the sky would be virtually impossible using current technology. There definitely would be people trying to figure out the trick and the only way I could see it work is if he would put a semi invisibility spell on himself to make him look a bit transparent or something.

Comment: @DavidMulder The people trying to figure him out, after he has been officially debunked will most likely only be some nerds and conspiracy theorists (as they are viewed by society) - he can mostly ignore them, even if they discover he is using magic, no one will much care about them. Many will even think they are hired by the magicians PR-Team to create an air of mystery... You could even let leak some information which looks like you payed them for their "shocking discovery or real magic" ^^

Comment: @Falco Gotta say I like that last idea xD But you would be surprised how big the community is that enjoys figuring out magic tricks, the kind of people who watch pen & teller: fool us for example and magicians that try to learn from each other. Honestly, the danger wouldn't be from conspiracy theorists, but just people trying to figure out his tricks and suddenly catching him (on camera) doing something that is *physically* impossible. To a lay person magicians do such things all the time, but to this crowd the difference is huge and it could mean trouble as they can be quite persistent.

Comment: @DavidMulder it is a danger... But you could try to mitigate it by letting leak really good photoshopped videos of you doing amazing tricks. If it is a lot of work to find out they are faked, most people will likely dismiss future videos as equally good fakes and not go to the trouble of analyzing it with the same effort...

Comment: One potential problem with this though is it could effect his life in various ways. People wouldn't trust them. This is only potential though because he doesn't care.

Answer (score 10):

Simple.  He needs to pretend to be an alien.
Mount a bunch of LEDs on his wand and call it a sonic screwdriver.
Caste an illusion of a flying saucer landing in the Capital.  Teleport (or invisibly walk) to the middle of the illusionary saucer, then open a hatch and (visibly) step out into the public view, before having the illusionary saucer fly away.

From that point on, he can do whatever he wants.  No more spells need to be wasted to defend his magic from discovery.

When the scientists raise a skeptical eye, all he has to do is say that he can't explain how his science works, because...

That would be breaking the Prime Directive!

Comment: -1 Aliens definitely would freak out scientists... and they definitely would give him a lot of attention as the scientists would wish to steal his knowledge and/or he would be expected to share his knowledge.

Comment: @DavidMulder You realize you never actually downvoted, right?

Comment: You were absolutely right, normally I downvote first and then realize I should justify it a bit. This time I started with a comment and then realized my criticism was hard enough to deserve a downvote so I edited in the -1 , but afterwards somehow forgot voting down. Oops :$

Comment: You implying Time Lord?

Comment: Not exclusively.  I stole from all the greats... Doctor Who, The Day The Earth Stood Still, and Star-Trek.

Answer (score 7):

Fundamentally, if stuck to all the requirement, this cannot be done.

But if you were to do it, the most ironcast method would be by demonstrating that the magician understands how the magic works, and can rationalise and predict what will happen when it's used.

At this point, magic can be proven as real, and the magician in question has essentially founded *the science of magic*, aka *theoretical magic* in the process of explaining it.

Science as defined by Wikipedia is:

> Science is a systematic enterprise that builds and organizes knowledge in the form of testable explanations and predictions about the universe

The idea of something that is by its nature is unscientific, and exists in the world, is meaningless, and suggests a misunderstanding of what the scientific principle is. It's similar to saying that you have water that is free of chemicals ( despite H2O being a chemical, along with anything else built from atoms ), the statement makes little sense.

As for the proposed solution, this has happened in the past! Although the theories put forward were eventually disproven as it was found that other explanations were more likely. For example, theories of **Alchemy** lead to the theories of chemistry. **Thaumaturgy** eventually lent itself to the existing fields of philosophy, and most of its aspects were shown to be less than rigorous. **Homeopathy** is a more recent attempt that has failed scientific enquiry, yet is recent enough to still encounter strong support.

The main difference here is that in your fictional world, this magician has actual magic, and can back up their statements. By explaining the mechanisms by which magic works, and providing empirical evidence to back up said hypothesis, the magic moves from a scientific hypothesis, to a scientific theory.

Without this, the likely reaction is that the magician is a charlatan and a liar, who tries to fool people into believing they have supernatural powers through trickery. Plenty such people already exist in our world, and if the magician demonstrates sufficient magical abilities, they may be seen as using technology as yet to be revealed

Now the question does state that the magic needs to be explained using current science, but this demonstrates a misunderstanding of science works.

> Specifically, it has to have a specific scientific explanation. Most scientists believe that everything fits into science, but this magician wants them to know how his magic fits in.

Nevermind that the statement "scientists believe that everything fits into science" is simply false ( dark energy, dark matter, the internal nature of black holes, where gravity comes from, etc to name a few ), **the very act of doing this creates a hypothesis on which the scientific principle can be applied**. New science has been created.

- Hypothesis: Expected answer to OP question
- Experiment: Test that explanation works
- Result: Evidence that can be used to construct a new theory

Lets say that your magicians only trick was a vast light show in the sky, and your magician decided to tell the scientists that he used a hidden wide field laser to shift the atoms in the air into a bose einstein state usually only seen in laboratories studying quantum states. This seems sensible at first, but your magician has unwittingly made a huge advance in quantum mechanics, one that will need to be reproducible.

Which is another vital element. For your magician to be believed, whatever they say needs to be explained in a way that other scientists can reproduce. **If it cannot be independently reproduced, then your magician will be accused of falsifying evidence and lieing, and you're back to square 1**

As a further note, if I make a claim that all people with the name Veronica have a secret ability to shoot beams of fire out of their palms that they are unaware of, I have created a Scientific Hypothesis. The current understanding of Science has changed. Granted, that hypothesis will not be taken seriously, and I highly doubt it will stand up when tested. But if it were tested, and reproduced, the general understanding of Veronica fire beams will be the theory.

**All in all, if we strictly adhere to the original questions parameters, the answer is no. It cannot be done without fundamentally changing the scientific method, and demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding about what science is, and how science works by the asker**

Comment: He wants them rationalize it with current science, not new science.

Comment: This may not be the answer you/he was looking for, but it's actually a very good one. "Any science which can be distinguished from magic is not sufficiently advanced." -- Florence Ambrose [Lead character in the _Freefall_ webcomic, highly recommended.]

Comment: @PyRulez the moment you rationalised it you've created new science, even the very presence of said magician doing said acts without attempting to explain it will involve new science the moment any person observes it and tries to think of an explanation ( aka create a hypothesis ). Current science has extensively documented the psychology of it, people will jump to absurd conclusions because we're uncomfortable being confronted with someone that we're unable to explain, your magicians probably going to face utterly stupid accusations of alien tech, spirit powers, divine godly intervention etc

Comment: I've updated the answer accordingly. The question as originally asked is contradictory if strictly stuck to

Comment: Well, strictly they are doing a little bit of science. But I mean, it should be no more science than when someone is, say, inventing something.

Comment: "Without this, the likely reaction is that the magician is a charlatan and a liar, who tries to fool people into believing they have supernatural powers through trickery". Read this again. And again, again, again. The **only** one who knows that it is not trickery is the magician **himself** and he has no interest to set up new theories or back up his powers. Scientists on the other hand choose what they want to explore and a real magician sounds so improbable that they fear to waste their time if an easier explanation is available. So, no inquiry.

Comment: It would only take 1 scientist to observe and be interested, even if thousands dismiss it as trickery, plenty of scientists deal with supernatural stuff in the present that most of us consider nonsense, but you're probably right for the majority, it all depends exactly what magical things this person is doing

Comment: You know that being a scientist interested in supernatural phenomena makes you to be a pariah in the scientific community ? Brian Josephson ("Telepathy is utter rubish !" David Deutsch) and Rupert Sheldrake (Nature: A book for burning ?) are examples. You are naive if you think that they are discussed fairly; an even mild TED from Sheldrake was censored and viciously and unfairly attacked by other scientists.

Comment: No hard reproducible solid empirical evidence was produced for those however, and the default response to scientific enquiry is doubt. In a healthy scientific field, the standard assumption is you're wrong, and the approach you take is that you try to disprove your theory ( attempting to prove telepathy and succeeding is laughable. Attempting to disprove telepathy and failing is interesting science that demands further study )

Comment: @TomJNowell I am sorry, but my experience (I was User13486) [says otherwise](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2578/do-dogs-know-when-their-owner-is-coming-home-through-some-form-of-telepathic-lin). Before I looked it up, *noone* read the original papers because *everyone* was utterly convinced that it is wrong and gave wrong arguments. The critics even tried to argue about the content *without reading the PDF* ! Did you ever tried to look up who exactly claimed that "no hard reproducible solid empirical evidence" exists and how they came to the conclusion ?

Comment: You yourself are the example that refutes your claim. If nobody will look at it, why did you? The top answer to that question also links to content by the author of said study, but we're not here to discuss telepathic dogs. Even if the odds are 1 in a million of someone not dismissing it, that's still a lot of scientists paying attention

Comment: @TomJNowell My claim was:"**Before** I looked it up, noone read the original papers", so it is not true that my claim was refuted. I tell you why I looked it up. In the past I wanted to test the claim "Scientists will always investigate a claim". I chose cold fusion because a) there were two reputable researchers b) The claim was fantastic, but published in a peer reviewed journal c) The experiment could be reproduced easily. So I looked up *how many of the over 1 Mio. scientists in the world actually tested the claim in the first month before the refutations came in*. Make an estimate.

Comment: I think this can be summed up as a "Not all scientists" type scenario, and I imagine in the universe the magician lives in, that there may be a Thorsten S. alive. If so I am vindicated. This isn't a cold fusion or a telepathic dog question, and the actions of the general scientific community at large are irrelevant here, all it takes is 1 person, the rest can be millions of monkeys flinging faeces at the magician, it doesn't really matter. Tbh this discussion doesn't belong in comments, and you'd be better asking the question on Skeptics

Comment: It does matter because IMHO your conclusion above is wrong. You are right that it is not a question if sth like cold fusion/telepathy exist, but if and how the magician *needs to explain his abilities to avoid scientists freaking out*. You claim it cannot be done because scientists  will expose him by failed replication. I say no, *the scientists* will assume trickery and ignore him without asking questions or even try to replicate it. After that, its *one scientist*. I say you can always say that this scientist is a crank. You say it would depend on evidence. (continued)

Comment: I say, nope, they wont even look at your evidence and falsely claim that there is none. Lets say, I really monitored the magician and put together the best evidence I get. How useful is that ? There are many scientists out there believing in strange ideas, how do you know that I am really trustable and the material is not a fake ? It really does matter if I am able to reach out and convince other people that the magician can really do magic. Do you experience that politicians inevitably fall down if their wrongdoings are exposed ? In my reality, sometimes yes, but very often *no*.

Comment: This is the point I would have made had you not already done it better.  **Science** is **demonstrable** and **reproducible**.  If the scientists can't reproduce his results using his claimed methods, they won't accept it as science -- he's obviously a fake.

Answer (score 6):

He won't actually have to do much work, the default position of a scientist is going to be that he's using sleight of hand, etc - so as long as he doesn't do anything that could not be faked then he will be fine.

The flying to work is the thing that's going to be a real problem, he shouldn't do that as long distance flying in uncontrolled outdoor spaces would be really hard to explain.

The problem you have is that explaining his activities and carnying on as normal are not compatible. Magic breaks any number of physical laws and as soon as he becomes blatant enough and gets enough people interested the fact that he is doing so will pretty soon be obvious.

However if he just moderates things a little when in public he can get away with a lot. The best thing is he never has to explain how he does it, he can just say "a magician never reveals his secrets" and let everyone else do the explaining for him...

Comment: "Mr. Magician, how did you fly to our house?" "A magician never reveals his secrets!"

Comment: "Clearly he has a helicopter hiding in the clouds carrying him. Right ,Mr. Magician?" "I will never tell!"

Answer (score 5):

[Niven's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_laws) states:

```
"Any sufficiently advanced magic is indistinguishable from technology."
```

Your magician does not need to do anything beyond claim that it is done with technology (i.e. it is indeed a trick), while withholding the method on the basis of intellectual property and commercial confidence. The fact that it really is magic need only be known to him.

For practical purposes you might like to have your magician keep an eye on anyone investigating his methods too closely and take subtle action to thwart them.

Comment: "take subtle action to thwart them." Would teleporting there house to another plane be subtle enough?

Comment: That would depend on whether they were home at the time. :-)

Comment: I'd like to add on this, in that if he can teleport at a whim, people wont see it at magic but that SOMETHING, SOMEWHERE allows him to teleport, or that his brain has some control over time/space etc... a scientific explanation to something 'currently' unexplainable

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to keep this story somewhat believable:

If he just wants to troll people, he can most likely get away with declaring them tricks - because no one is going to care too much.

If he does anything that's actually useful, that won't fly. People will want to know how he does it. He *will* have to come up with an explanation. Assuming the scientists of your universe are not grossly incompetent, that explanation will have to work.

In other words, your hypothetical wizard could only use spells that allow him to do things that are not only physically possible, but also possible to implement with the equipment a person carries on themselves. That kind of defeats the whole point of your idea though.

Unless you *severely* restrict the abilities of your wizard he will live in a rather odd caricature of our world where people can easily get away with pretend science. It'd really only work if somehow no actual scientist ever heard of him. Maybe you can put him in a remote mountain village with no internet access or something.

Answer (score 3):

It would depend on the details of what this magician wanted to do. When I am told that someone has the powers of a D&D wizard, I assume a level 20 D&D 3.5 wizard, the maximum according to standard rules (no epic-level fluff). This actually gives the wizard a great number of options. Some people have suggested that the magician could simply do whatever he wished, and people would simply explain it away as illusion. While this might be true within certain, very limited contexts, there is simply no way that summoning a demon out of thin air, for example, if witnessed by many people, will be dismissed as a mass delusion (something which occurs infrequently enough, and only in response to specific social situations). Those who suggest that a new branch of "science" will be thought up to explain his actions if he is too blatant about it are spot-on. I hesitate to call anything that treats conscious minds separately "science," but perhaps empiricism. Fortunately, the wizard need not find himself in this situation. The wizard has many options for concealing or disguising his sorcery.

Option 1: Invisibility. The spells *persistent invisibility* and *superior invisibility* are incredibly useful here. The first is an 8th level persistent spell that lasts all day. So our wizard can cast once and make himself invisible all day. The latter is a spell that lasts 20 minutes (for a 20th-level caster), but also conceals from hearing, and scent, and allows him to attack without dispelling the charm. It may, however, prevent the casting of spells with a verbal component. These spells could conceal any bizarre effect that the wizard does to himself (e.g. shapeshifting) quite effectively. Even bizarre summoned (or called) creatures could be concealed in a similar manner. The first does not conceal sound, but the chances that someone would here a peculiar sound, and conclude that magic was at work, are extremely low. What is more, the second presents some incredible possibilities. The wizard wants to hit someone with a bolt of electricity? He simply casts *fly*, goes up in the air, and fires the lightning bolt. With no individual in sight, this event, while obviously supernatural if the wizard were visible, will likely be brushed off as simply a "bolt from the blue." This method, while certainly meaning that the wizard's spells can easily be passed off as having a scientific explanation, does have the disadvantage that the wizard is trying to hide them. This, I think, was prohibited in your explanation.

Option 2: Concealing as mundane. This, I think, is more along the lines of what you are looking for. A wizard who sticks to the conjuration of small objects and animals can likely pass himself off as a party magician, regardless of how frequently he does so. Quite a number of conjuration spells could plausibly be passed off as completely mundane. For example: The spell *prestidigitation* produces small effects that look like magic tricks. *Grease* can easily be passed off as having some of the real thing hidden in a sleeve. *Comprehend languages* is simply the mark of a polyglot. Most illusion spells, if they do not cover an extremely large area or strike people dead, are easily passed off as, well, illusions. Any divination spell is simply either a good guess, the action of a confederate, or prior planning. The spell *summon swarm*, done in an appropriate area, is readily explained away as the result of animals placed there beforehand. Even some of the more powerful, high-level spells can be explained in scientific terms. A *temporal stasis* spell, if cast on an animal or some other creature incapable of relaying its experiences, looks a lot like a magic trick. *Astral projection* is extremely powerful, but produces few effects that would be evident to observers, besides unconsciousness, which is easily explained away. *Shapechange* is easy. A wizard jumps into a closet. A mosquito flies out (or an incorporeal or gaseous creature drifts out). Everyone murmurs appreciatively and looks for hidden doors. This same sort of trick is done without magic all the time.

Option 3: *Time stop*. Yes, the D&D wizard, at the highest levels, has a limited ability to stop time. For anywhere from 12 to 30 seconds, the wizard can do pretty much anything, anywhere, and no one will notice. The wizard can throw fireballs, shoot lightning, turn into a demon, conjure things, and as long as no obvious residue of the spell is left when the stopped time ends, no one will notice a thing. What is more, even if some huge effect is created during the time stop, a powerful illusion spell such as *screen* can be used to prevent the object from being seen or heard. Even better, no one will have any chance of resisting the effect unless they have good reason to believe that a wizard just conjured a wall of iron and concealed it with magic.

I think that the previous options give a sufficiently intelligent wizard (and pretty much all 20th-level wizards have a 180 IQ anyway) plenty of ways of casting spells, even technically within plain sight of Muggles, without anything out of the ordinary being noticed.

To attend to one specific issue. Your wizard wants to fly to work, in plain sight of everyone, and have it be viewed as perfectly natural. No problem! The spell *levitate* would allow a level 20 wizard to move a 2000 pound object through the air for up to 20 minutes. Needless to say, a *persistent levitate* would last all day. What the wizard can then do is commission a 2000 pound machine that looks as though it might be capable of flight (has wings, makes loud engine noises, etc). Then the wizard could use a day-long levitate spell to get it at a constant height, and then *fly* to work, appearing to sit the front seat of the conveyance, while really pulling the now-weightless machine along with him. A titanium car with wings and extremely powerful engines could quite possibly achieve flight at an atrocious energy cost, so if the (presumably very rich, thanks to divination) wizard has some plausible looking models built, these can be used to conceal a leisurely flight to work, without really needing to use incredible amounts of rocket fuel.

Answer (score 2):

Seriously ?

It is almost impossible to be exposed as long as the magician claims to be a conjurer and using "tricks" to do his bidding. The default option of the scientists is that conjurers work are uninteresting from a scientific perspective because they are tricks.

Necessarily magicians will be impressed by the quality of the tricks and jealous, but they cannot do much either.

Suppose he is flying to work and I want to expose him. "Yes, Mr. T., you saw him flying to work. Let me show you the door." I tape him flying. "Mr. T., you are insulting my intelligence. Do you think I believe your crude fake video ?!". Other people are joining in and attest that they have him seen flying, too. "A severe case of mass delusion".
And if it is going to be much trouble, simply as one answer already point out, go to a magician and get "debunked" that it really was a trick and even if I and the others protested that the demonstration is not remotely the same thing as that what we saw, we will be ignored.

I would like to add that the magician will sooner or later acquire some groupies, especially of the esoteric branch. While it may have advantages for selecting some mates, that could be more trouble for him than scientists.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, when constructing a hypothetical question you create a self contradictory scenario without noticing. 'Science' encompasses any phenomenon that is measurable and observable. The only reason that 'science' does not encompass 'magic' is because it is assumed to be fictional and therefore not measurable or observable. As soon as there existed a magician to do magic in front of scientist, the 'magic' would be 'observable' and therefore NOT 'unscientific'. Scientist would not require any persuasion to begin attempting empirical measurements and/or investigations and/or hypothesising, etc. etc. etc. There is no scenario in which a scientist could be convinced that something observable and measurable is 'not science' since the very definition of science explicitly encompasses all such things.

In practice however, the majority of scientist would approach it with the assumption that it was a hoax, since, on the surface, it seems to violate scientific laws. They would then either lose interest after they had failed to explain how the trick works scientifically, or they would come up with some plausible hypothesis about how it 'might' be explained and be content to assume that they are probably correct.

So probably the fastest way to lose the interest of scientist would be to actively proclaim a message along the lines of: "This is real magic! This is not a trick! Don't listen to those stupid scientists; they are out to rob you of your joy! Just believe in magic and you can join me! Also, I accept donations."

Comment: You are right about the science approach, but there is a much chance he would be coerced into a guinnea pig job to test and re-test new scientific theories. And that, in any case, defeat the wizzard wish to *"[want] scientists to believe his acts fit within current science"* as required in the question. Maybe you can adress these issues..?

Comment: Take the UK TV magician 'Dinamo' for example. From where I stand, his tricks are quite convincing. I have no explanation for how his tricks might work. Actually, I have no proof that he isn't using "Real Magic." (apart from the rather cyclic argument that 'magic isn't real and therefore all magic is fake') Has he been coerced into being a lab rat for scientists? Why would an 'actual wizard' be any different? For that matter, how do you know that 'Dinamo' isn't an 'Actual wizard'?

Comment: While it may be strictly self-contradictory, I feel that the intent of the question is clear. Using quantum mechanics to provide a plausible explanation for the sorcery is one thing. Simply saying that it is science because you can see it is not enough. After all, the wizard wants to keep his gifts secret. In addition, though, some definitions of science, as well as common usage, limit it to the physical or natural world. When the mind can alter the base laws of reality, rather than being altered by them, there is a decent argument for calling it "non-physical."

Comment: Fair Enough. We should take this question to mean "How could someone who can alter physical reality using only his mind, convince scientists that his methods are actually limited to the application of well understood physical principles and not worth investigating further?" As the second part of my answer alludes to, the fastest way to lose the interests of scientists is to proclaim "This is real magic! This is not a trick! Don't listen to those stupid scientists; they are out to rob you of your joy! Just believe in magic and you can join me! Also, I accept donations."

Answer (score 1):

Eat a lot, or talk to a string theorist.

The world contains beings that can snap their claws to stun prey infront of them (without touching them with the claws), that can spray boiling water to cook their prey, that can change shape, size, color and spit acid, ink and venom. Time can already run slower for some beings than others and twins can age faster than the other twin. It is possible (a little unlikely) for all of the atoms of a person to disappear, and reappear in the same configuration in a different location. Pretty much every dnd spell is completely boring compared to the insane things that go on in reality.

The thing that DnD wizards can do that nothing in the real world can is create energy. To hide this, the wizard must appear to eat a lot. Possibly teleporting the food away from their throat so they don't become full or fat.

Alternatively, you could probably convince scientists that the energy is being harnessed from 'somewhere else' instead of being created. Between multiverse theories, the idea of energy being stored in tiny vibrating string dimensions, and plain old dark energy, scientists are comfortable with the idea that we can lose and find energy, as long as they can somewhat confidently state that is has been not been created or destroyed. Particularly, this will be easy for scientists to believe given the wizard could objectively prove the existence of different planes

Additionally, as possibly a more believable explanation for instantaneous teleportation available in dnd than co-ordinated quantum teleportation of macro objects is the use of higher level dimensions, such as found in string theory and proposed by somewhat rational scientists for many years, such as the Alcubierre drive, "which proposes expanding the fabric of space behind a ship and shrinking space-time in front of the ship. The ship would not actually move, rather the ship would sit in a bubble between the expanding and shrinking space-time dimensions. Since space would move around the ship, the theory does not violate Einstein's Theory of Relativity, which states that it would take an infinite amount of energy to accelerate a massive object to the speed of light." - http://newswise.com/articles/view/543391/

Comment: I'm being picky here, but "dimension" as in "alternate dimension" is not a science term - it is a science *fiction* term.  Mainly because "dimension" already has a specific scientific meaning.  A scientist might call it an alternative universe or a parallel universe or some such thing, but definitely not a dimension.

Comment: Actually, scientists who study string theory do exactly that. They refer to the possibility of taking a shortcut through the additional dimensions proposed by String Theory, including this article, in which neutrinos "take shortcuts through the extra dimensions predicted by string theory."

http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/dimensional-shortcuts/

Comment: The "extra dimensions" predicted by string theory are dimensions in the scientific sense - the same way time is a dimension - not in the "parallel dimensions" sense.  The article you've linked to is behind a paywall, so I can't see it, but I suspect you're misinterpreting it, or the article misinterprets the research - possibly because of this very confusion over what "extra dimension" means to a scientist.

Comment: You're right. I initially had 2 points there, decided to cut down to one, but managed to make my cuts poorly, and it was pretty poorly worded to begin with.

Comment: No worries, I only mentioned it because this is a particularly common misconception, and one a science fiction writer needs to avoid.  Your new revision is much better.  Just in case anyone is wondering how you can "take a shortcut through an extra dimension": imagine you have to circumnavigate a pyramid.  You can find a shorter route by making use of the extra dimension commonly known as "up". :-)